# Environment variables are getting fetched after build deploy to S3 is Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables, production-environment

I have used Github Actions to build and deploy the Vue app to the S3 bucket. The problem is, the build script cannot fetch ENV from the `.env` or `.env.production` files, as those are not added in the commit.

I'm getting `undefined` when I log the ENV variables in my `created()` hook. As there are only two that are available, but the ones I wanted:

[image]

.env & .env.production as of now exactly the same:

```
VUE_APP_RZ_KEY=<Secret_Key>
VUE_APP_API_URL=<API_URL>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my_app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "npm run lint && vue-cli-service serve",
    "serve:prod": "npm run lint && vue-cli-service serve --production",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build --mode production",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.11",
    "vue-axios": "^3.2.5",
    "vue-router": "^3.2.0"
  },
...
}
```

Github Action `.yaml` file:

[image]

How do I make my ENVs make it to the built?

Answer (score 0):

I propose to add the end data to GitHub Secrets.